# Font shapes undefined and unavailable

Tags: warnings

In TexMaker using TexLive I get the following warning

[image]

Due to that warning text that should be bold and large is neither. The code runs normally on ShareLaTeX though.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text,
    Extension = .otf
]{GFSDidot}


\begin{document}

\textbf{Text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently your local GFS Didot font is missing boldface.

Comment: @egreg I have installed the full TexLive and apparently GFSDidot is installed so how can it only miss the bold? :P

Comment: As usual, a minimal example of code is needed.

Comment: @egreg I added a MWE but it doesn't contain anything special that is why I didn't do it earlier.

Comment: On TeX Live, the font files for italic, bold and bold italic are named `GFSDidotItalic.otf`, `GFSDidotBold.otf` and `GFSDidotBoldItalic.otf`. I get loads of errors with your code. If I use the correct names, I get no warning.

Comment: @egreg I corrected it and I get no warning! I think that this was what you meant.

`\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = GFSDidotBold.otf,
    ItalicFont = GFSDidotItalic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = GFSDidotBoldItalic.otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text,
]{GFSDidot.otf}`

Comment: @egreg Ok! Thank you very much. If you want you can add your comment as a question so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how that code can work in ShareLaTeX, because the font files in TeX Live that provide the GFS Didot font are named

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsdidot/GFSDidot.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsdidot/GFSDidotBold.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsdidot/GFSDidotBoldItalic.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsdidot/GFSDidotItalic.otf
```

and they have always been the same (I checked back to TeX Live 2012)

I guess the names are the same in MiKTeX (the location of course will differ).

Change the font definition as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  UprightFont = *,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  ItalicFont = *Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldItalic,
  Extension = .otf,
]{GFSDidot}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Text}

\end{document}
```

Note that `Ligatures=TeX` is transformed (in XeLaTeX) into `Mapping=tex-text`, so the latter is unneeded if the former is given. And `Ligatures=TeX` is automatically set by `fontspec`, unless explicitly overridden.

Comment: Thank you and I believe that your answer is right but the only way to get rid of the warnings is by writing `\setmainfont[
  UprightFont = *,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  ItalicFont = *Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldItalic,
  Extension = .otf,
]{GFSDidot}`